# $e^x \neq 0$ Proof Correctness

Tags: limits, proof-verification, exponential-function

*note*: I’m not looking for another proof for this, I am just asking if this proof is correct.

This is my proof.

Assume $f(x)=e^x=0$

Then $e^\frac{x}{2}e^\frac{x}{2}=0$

More generally, $(e^\frac{x}{n})^n=0$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}1^n=1$

That means $1=0$ hence the contradiction.

Comment: I don't follow the proof since the first limit, should it be $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x/n)$ perhaps? And why does that come out to $1^n$?

Comment: @Joppy It comes out to $1^n$ because I took the limit of $e^\frac{x}{n}$ first which equals 1.

Comment: It is quite clear from the expansion of $e^x$ that $e^x > 0$ for $x>0$ Now observe that $e^x\cdot e^{-x} = 1.$ So $e^{-x} \neq 0.$

Comment: You can't evaluate limits like $(e^{\frac{x}{n}})^n$ "one at a time"

Comment: Why cant you do that?

Comment: For example, we have for any positive number $a$ that $(a^{\frac{1}{n}})^n = a$. However, if we take the limit $n \to \infty$ and evalute the innermost first, we would get $a^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, and then the outermost limit would be $1^n \to 1$. But the answer is $a$, not $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof is not correct because it assumes implicitely that if a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}^n=1$. This is not true. For instance,$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left (1 + \frac1n \right )=1\text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n=e\neq1.$$